# css code partially working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design an resume using Html,CSS.while doing this getting error on color display,and change in size. i am sending my zip file with full implementation . There is one image name sample,this is the required resume to be design?kindly help me for this.

Html code given below:

```css
#main container {
  back ground-color: "#DDD6D5";
  text align: center;
}
#main container >a {
  bgcolor: "#DEB6AD";
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
# horizontal nav {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  back ground-color: "red";
}
#summary {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
#work experience1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  ;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: thick;
  border-top-width: thick;
}
#work experience2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  ;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: thick;
  border-top-width: thick;
}
#work experience3 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  ;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: thick;
  border-top-width: thick;
}
#work experience4 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  ;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  border-bottom-width: thick;
  border-top-width: thick;
}
#education {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
}
#certificate {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
#language {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
#technical skill {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Alexander Krasner-cv</title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<body>
  <div id="main container" ;bgcolor="red">
    <p>
      <h1> ALEXANDER KRASNER</h1>
      <h2>Java Developer </h2>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="horizontal nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="image\mobile.png">
        <b>123456789</b>
        <img src="image\mail.png">
        <b>alexander12@gmail.com</b>
        <img src="image\location.png">
        <b> 15 Jacksonville Road,Middleburg,FL 33486</b>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
      <div id="summary">
        <h1>SUMMARY</h1>
        <b>Sun certified programmer for java platform   </b>
        <br/>
        <b>over 6 year of IT experience</b>
        <br/>
        <b>excellent java development skill using J2EE,J2SE ,servalet,jdbc,applet ,java bc.</b>
        <br/>
        <b>Strong data base connectivity skills IBM DB2,MS SQL SERVER ,MYSQL,Acess </b>
        <br/>
        <b>Experience encompassess software design,maintainance for custom application
        .Exclusive OBJECT ORIENTED Experience,OOP/OOD Experience</b>
        <br/>
        <b>Encompassess software design,maintainance for custom application.</b>
        <br/>
      </div>

      <div id="Work Experience1">
        <h1>WORK EXPERIENCE11111</h1>
        <img src="image\date-icon.jpg">
        <h3>SmartSoft Technologies-Florida,USA System Programmer/Analyst</h3>
        <p>
          <h5>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui  officia deserunt Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit. sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia. deserunt Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
               Vconsectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
               Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
                Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h5>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="Work Experience2">
        <h1>WORK EXPERIENCE 2222</h1>
        <img src="image\date-icon.jpg">
        <h3>SmartSoft Technologies-Florida,USA System Programmer/Analyst</h3>
        <p>
          <h5>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
      deserunt Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.
            sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt Excepteur sint occaecat 
      cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.
              deserunt Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
           Vconsectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
           Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h5>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div id="Work Experience3">
        <h1>WORK EXPERIENCE 3333</h1>
        <img src="image\date-icon.jpg">
        <h3>SmartSoft Technologies-Florida,USA System Programmer/Analyst</h3>
        <p>
          <h5>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
      sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.
              sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.
            deserunt Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.
           Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
            Vconsectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
             Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
               Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h5>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div id="Work Experience4">
        <h1>WORK EXPERIENCE 4444</h1>
        <img src="image\date-icon.jpg">
        <h3>SmartSoft Technologies-Florida,USA System Programmer/Analyst</h3>
        <p>
          <h5>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.
             sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia.
             deserunt Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.
            Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
            Vconsectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
             Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
          Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h5>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;width:50%;">
      <div id="education">
        <h1>EDUCATION</h1>
        <img src="image\date-icon.jpg">
        <b><h2>Master Degree in Computer Science</h2></b>
        <h3>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt </h3>
        <b><h2>Bachelor Degree in Computer Science</h2></b>
        <h3>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt </h3>

      </div>

      <div id="certificate">
        <h1>CERTIFICATE</h1>
        <h3>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit.
         sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
          sunt in culpa qui officia. deserunt Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit. Ut enim ad minim veniam</h3>
      </div>

      <div id="Language">
        <h1>LANGUAGE</h1>
        <h3>English,Spanish</h3>
      </div>

      <div id="Technical Skills">
        <h1>TECHNICAL SKILLS</h1>
        <img src="image\CHART.jpg">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img src="image\red.png">
            <b>Programming language:Java j2EE,Sun Java,Visual Basic</b>
            <br/>
            <img src="image\blue.png">
            <b>Programming language:Java j2EE,Sun Java,Visual Basic</b>
            <br/>
            <img src="image\yellow.png">
            <b>Programming language:Java j2EE,Sun Java,Visual Basic</b>
            <br/>
            <img src="image\green.png">
            <b>Programming language:Java j2EE,Sun Java,Visual Basic</b>
            <br/>
            <img src="image\pink.png">
            <b>Programming language:Java j2EE,Sun Java,Visual Basic</b>
            <br/>
            <img src="image\br.png">
            <b>Programming language:Java j2EE,Sun Java,Visual Basic</b>
            <br/>
            <img src="image\lightbl.png">
            <b>Programming language:Java j2EE,Sun Java,Visual Basic</b>
            <br/>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Required image for sample resume
[image: IMAGE FOR DESIGN RESUME, All the coding is done according to it.]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeFuK.jpg):

Comment: The major issue with the CSS, HTML is that you cannot have spaces in the ID name. Since a space in ID will turn out a different CSS selector altogether. eg #technical skill in the CSS will mean that you are referring to element "skill" which is a child of element with id "technical" which itself is invalid and not what you want. Remove the spaces from ID name in the HTML and from the CSS.

Comment: It would be great if you can make a jsfiddle and share its link.

Comment: The problem is not described accurately. The code also contains a lot of typo's, Try to correct that first. For instance the bgcolor attribute in <div id= "main container";bgcolor="red"> is invalid. The CSS file contains a space between back and ground in `back ground-color:"red";` and the double quotes are not required.

Answer (score 0):

## image path in HTML

you should not use  backslashes in image paths:

### Wrong:

```
<img src="image\mobile.png">
```

### Wright:

```
<img src="image/mobile.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments seem to basically solve your answer. IDs and classes may not have spaces, therefore elements such as `# horizontal nav {` should be `#horizontalnav` (no spaces); alternatively, you can however use capital letters such as `#horizontalNav` or hyphens such as `#horizontal-nav`.